# How to display date in jsp，such as "2017-08-30 14:35:43"

Tags: java, html, jsp

I meet some trouble in jsp page!

This is my part of code in jsp:

```
<td class="td-char"><%=Tools.nvl(crs.getString("ryid"))%></td>
<td class="td_char"><%=Tools.nvl(crs.getString("name"))%></td>
<td class="td_char"><%=Tools.nvl(crs.getString("sfid"))%></td>
<td class="td_char"><%=Tools.nvl(crs.getString("sexname"))%></td>
<td class="td_char"><%=Tools.nvl(crs.getString("indate"))%></td>
<td class="td_char"><fmt:formatDate value="<%=Tools.nvl(crs.getString("indate"))%>" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"/> </td>
```

Why i solve it...

Comment: Can you add some comment to explain more your issue

Comment: You haven't told us what your problem is! We can't solve your problem if we don't know what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
 <%!String DisplayDate = "";%>
    <%
        String MyDate = Tools.nvl(crs.getString("indate"));
        SimpleDateFormat parseDate = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        SimpleDateFormat formatDate = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date;
        try {
            date = (Date) parseDate.parse(MyDate);
            DisplayDate = formatDate.format(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    %>

    <td class="td_char"><%=DisplayDate%></td>
```

Give your existing date format in line two as an input format(I have assumed it would be as `"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"` ).Make the necessary imports as well.

Comment: Do i need to import some packages?

Comment: import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

These will be the java imports

Comment: yeah. There are what i want! Thank you!